# Cannot mock function with jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to create a simple test with jest by mocking a few asynchronous functions

Here is the method I'm testing:

```
import { isUserAccountHolder } from '@helpers/userRoleManager';
import { getOrCreateVote } from '@helpers/voteManager';

type GetVoteLink = {
  campaignId: string;
  companyProfileId: string;
  companyUserId: string;
};

export const getVoteLink = async ({
  campaignId,
  companyProfileId,
  companyUserId,
}: GetVoteLinkProps) => {
  try {
    console.log('getVoteLink- start');

    const isAccountHolder = await isUserAccountHolder(
      companyProfileId,
      companyUserId,
    );

    if (!isAccountHolder) {
      console.log('user is not account holder');
      return 'https://www.google.fr';
    }

    console.log('user is account holder');
    const voteUrl = await getOrCreateVote(campaignId, companyProfileId);

    return voteUrl;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error('error:', { error });
    return 'https://www.google.fr';
  }
};
```

And here is my very basic test:

```
import photon from '@helpers/photon';
import { isUserAccountHolder } from '@helpers/userRoleManager';

import { getVoteLink } from '../src/services/myService';

const mockGetVote = jest.fn();
const mockGetToken = jest.fn();
const mockIsAccountHolder = jest.fn();


jest.mock('@helpers/voteManager', () => ({
  getVote: () => mockGetVote,
}));

jest.mock('@helpers/tokenManager', () => {
  return {
    getToken: () => mockGetToken,
  };
});

jest.mock('@helpers/userRoleManager', () => ({
  isUserAccountHolder: () => mockIsAccountHolder,
}));

describe('myService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockGetToken.mockResolvedValue('token');
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it.only('should return proper link if user is account holder', async () => {
    mockIsAccountHolder.mockResolvedValue(false);

    const voteLink = await getVoteLink({
      campaignId: 'campaignId',
      companyProfileId: 'companyProfileId',
      companyUserId: 'companyUserId',
    });

    expect(mockIsAccountHolder).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, when running those tests, it appears that the isAccountHolder value is always set to true, despite the fact that I set its resolved value to false, and the mockIsAccountHolder is never called.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: isUserAccountHolder is async, you may want to  `await mockIsAccountHolder.mockResolvedValue(false)` instead?    (jest docs show example) https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api/#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue